# Авто генерация колонок WPF DataGrid из массива

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Возникла необходимость автоматической генерации колонок в DataGrid WPF с привязкой значений к элементам списка булеанов. Датагрид имеет ширину, исходя из ширины экрана. Колонки должны иметь определенную конкретную ширину.

Список окончен - колонки не создаются, оставшееся место в датагриде - одна большая пустая колонка. Ряды по-прежнему генерируются для каждого объекта в передаваемом списке.

---

### Класс, объекты которого нужно привязать к датагриду

---

```
public class AccessLevel
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }
    public Boolean[] Rights { get; private set; }


    public AccessLevel()
    {

    }
}
```

Как я делал раньше:

---

### XAML.cs

---

```
List<AccessLevel> rights = getAllRights();
DataGrid.ItemsSource =  rights;
```

---

### XAML

---

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding GroupName}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
        <!--  ="Name"  -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Rights[0]}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Rights[1]}"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Но теперь возникла вероятность, что массив булеанов будет содержать разное количество элементов. 
Некоторые части кода упрощены ввиду ненадобности для рассмотрения конкретного случая

Comment: _"Колонки должны иметь определенную конкретную ширину"_ -- а если в настройках ОС display указан увеличенный размер шрифта, то ширина колонки должна меняться?

Comment: Я, признаться, такой случай даже не рассматривал. Наверное, да